# Why Bootstrap Datepicker does not revalidate

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
    **My HTML form is:**

<html>
  <body>

    <form role="form" class="margin_top" method="post" id="eventForm">

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group date form_date col-sm-12" data-date="" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input2" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd" id="datePicker">
                        <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" name="date_from" placeholder="Date of Arrival" readonly>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group date form_date col-sm-12" data-date="" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input2" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd" id="datePicker2">
                        <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" name="date_to" placeholder="Date of Departure" readonly>

                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="dtp_input2" value="" />
                </div>
      <button type="submit" name="send_request" class="btn btn-info bnt-md" value="send">Send Request</button>
    </form>
  </body>


   <script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#datePicker')
            .datepicker({
                format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
            })
            .on('changeDate', function(e) {
                // Revalidate the date field
                $('#eventForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'date_from');
        });
        $('#datePicker2')
            .datepicker({
                format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
            })
            .on('changeDate', function(e) {
                // Revalidate the date field
                $('#eventForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'date_to');
        });



        $('#eventForm').bootstrapValidator({
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                date_from: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The date is required'
                        },
                        date: {
                            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                            message: 'The date is not a valid'
                        }
                        }
                    },
                date_to: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The date is required'
                        },
                        date: {
                            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                            message: 'The date is not a valid'
                        }
                        }
                    }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker3.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.4.5/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"  charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

When i does not select any date from Datepicker and i submit the form then it shows error message "The date is require", so again i select a date from Datepicker then it shows same error message. it can't revalidate.
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, add bootstrapvalidator js and css file so i can check it.

Comment: hello, @MansukhKhandhar i added bootstrapvalidator js and css file to the above form.kindly check it

Comment: sumthing worn in above script. i my local server comes js error

TypeError: $(...).formValidation is not a function
$('#eventForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'date_from');

Comment: in above first required formValidation() main library.

Comment: how can i define formValidation() function in above.and what should be the code in this function?

Comment: formValidation() is define by you ?

Comment: ya, please fix the bug

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try this script may be help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#datePicker')
            .datepicker({
                format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
            })
            .on('changeDate', function(e) {
                // Revalidate the date field
                $('#eventForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'date_from');
        });
        $('#datePicker2')
            .datepicker({
                format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
            })
            .on('changeDate', function(e) {    
    if(new Date( $('#date1').val()) >= new Date($('#date2').val()))
    {
     alert('Set date proper !');
     jQuery('#date2').val('');
    }
    
                // Revalidate the date field
                //$('#eventForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'date_to');
        });
  
  (function( $ ){
   $.fn.formValidation = function(t1,t2) {
       // alert(t2);
       return this;
  }; 
  })( jQuery );


        $('#eventForm').bootstrapValidator({
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                date1: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The date is required'
                        },
                        date: {
                            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                            message: 'The date is not a valid'
                        }
                        }
                    },
                date12: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The date is required'
                        },
                        date: {
                            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                            message: 'The date is not a valid'
                        }
                        }
                    }
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.4.5/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

    <form role="form" class="margin_top" method="post" id="eventForm">

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group date form_date col-sm-12" data-date="" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input2" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd" id="datePicker">
                        <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" name="date_from" id="date1" placeholder="Date of Arrival" readonly>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group date form_date col-sm-12" data-date="" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input2" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd" id="datePicker2">
                        <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" name="date_to" placeholder="Date of Departure" id="date2" readonly>

                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="dtp_input2" value="" />
                </div>
      <button type="submit" name="send_request" class="btn btn-info bnt-md" value="send">Send Request</button>
    </form>
```

If any problem info me. because i am not sure what need you.

Comment: The added script only check 2nd date field that select is less then or equal to the 1st date field selected.but it does not revalidate. means it shows same error message, that is "The date is required"..its not working

Comment: in above demo can't display error "The date is required". in some problem in your extra script.if add extra script remove temporary and check it